# Error Super expression must either be null or a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, frontend, react-native-camera

I am trying to use a camera in React Native app but getting this error.

> error Super expression must either be null or a function.

I have used the code from the following link https://react-native-community.github.io/react-native-camera/docs/rncamera

```js
'use strict';
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native';
import { RNCamera } from 'react-native-camera';

class ExampleApp extends PureComponent {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <RNCamera
          ref={(ref) => {
            this.camera = ref;
          }}
          style={styles.preview}
          type={RNCamera.Constants.Type.back}
          flashMode={RNCamera.Constants.FlashMode.on}
          androidCameraPermissionOptions={{
            title: 'Permission to use camera',
            message: 'We need your permission to use your camera',
            buttonPositive: 'Ok',
            buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
          }}
          androidRecordAudioPermissionOptions={{
            title: 'Permission to use audio recording',
            message: 'We need your permission to use your audio',
            buttonPositive: 'Ok',
            buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
          }}
          onGoogleVisionBarcodesDetected={({ barcodes }) => {
            console.log(barcodes);
          }}
        />
        <View style={{ flex: 0, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.takePicture.bind(this)} style={styles.capture}>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 14 }}> SNAP </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }

  takePicture = async () => {
    if (this.camera) {
      const options = { quality: 0.5, base64: true };
      const data = await this.camera.takePictureAsync(options);
      console.log(data.uri);
    }
  };
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    backgroundColor: 'black',
  },
  preview: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  capture: {
    flex: 0,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    borderRadius: 5,
    padding: 15,
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    margin: 20,
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('App', () => ExampleApp);
```

Comment: What is the name of your file ? Can you show us your project file architecture ?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).It looks to me that there are many unnecessary codes there which makes it hard for you and the others to see the real cause of the problem!

Comment: I have used  '''npx react-native init AwesomeProject''' and paste this code from  https://react-native-community.github.io/react-native-camera/docs/rncamera in App.js @YanvegHD